# ASRock > TRX40 Taichi, Audio problem

Tags: boot, drivers, sound

Motherboard |       Asrock trx40 taichi

Processor|          AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3960X 24-Core Processor

Memory|             32796MB

Machine Type|       Desktop

Operating System|   Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

..........................................................................

The issue |         No Audio

Issue status|       Solved

..........................................................................

Explanation |

after the installation of Ubuntu 20.04, has been noticed that the system have no sound at all. the system detect the sound card. i tried every method provided online and the result is that the issue remain.
i installed Windows 10 pro and the same issue occurred.
i noticed that i have an < RTK BOOT> driver missing.
what solved my issue in both systems is this method .....>
https://www.asrock.com/support/faq.asp?k=boot

<
If there is a RTK device showing under the device manager and audio port cannot be used, please follow the steps below to remove the RTK device and allow the audio to work properly.

Step 1. Uninstall the Realtek audio driver.

Step 2. Install the Realtek audio driver ver.6.3.9600.2237 from the link below then restart the system.
Link:https://download.asrock.com/Drivers/All/Audio/Realtek_Audio(v6.3.9600.2237).zip

Step 3. Right-click the start icon in the desktop and select the device manager to see if there is RTK Boot showing in your system.

Step 4. Download and extract the Audio Flash Tool from the link below:
Link:https://download.asrock.com/TSD/Desktop/Tool/Audio Flash Tool.zip

Step 5. Double click the UacCodecDownload_AllInOne_RsProxy_2.64.10

Step 6. Press the Start button to start flashing the audio firmware.

Step 7. Once the flashing process is completed, the tool will show Pass which means audio firmware has successfully flashed and there should not be RTK boot device showing under the device manager.>

that's works for me at least.

The question | what was the problem?

Comment: Do you still have the file "Audio Flash Tool.zip"? The link no longer works and I can't find it anywhere. I've just bought the TRX40 Taichi and have the same problem. :/